# .NET Core Entity Framework linking subtable to property

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, foreign-keys

This is an existing .NET Core 3.1 project I inherited.

I have a class referring to a database table

```
public class SupportContract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int SupportContractStatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual SupportContractStatus SupportContractStatus { get; set; }
}
```

and a sub table with a foreign key

```
public class SupportContractStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SupportContractStatusName { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine I can get

```
supportContract.SupportContractStatus.SupportContractStatusName
```

But if I rename `SupportContractStatusId` to `ContractStatusId` in C# and the database, I get an error "SupportContractStatusId missing".

I cannot find any link between the column `SupportContractStatusId` and table `SupportContractStatus` anywhere in code nor is there any mention of the foreign key.

There is no link in the `DbContext` either.

Is this naming convention assumed by Entity Framework? How does the framework know of the foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the naming convention that EF expects by default is based on the class name, not the property name. It will look for ClassNameId or ClassName_Id. You can link the FK either through annotation or configuration.

I.e.

```
public int ContractStatusId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ContractStatusId")]
public virtual SupportContractStatus ContractStatus { get; set; }
```

Configuration is done through `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementations or by implementing the `OnModelCreating` method in the DbContext and configuring the relationship within the modelBuilder. For occasional deviations from convention, the attribute approach can generally cover everything.